# Add shipping address to Woocommerce order emails

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, email

After upgrading my Woocommerce to 2.6.6 - new order emails only show billing address and not shipping address.  Can I manually add shipping address to my emails?

The code I have is

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );
```

But it seems that woocommerce_email_customer_details does not print the shipping address.  Can I override or hard code the shipping address in?

Answer (score 2):

To call the shipping address:

```
<p><?php echo $order->get_formatted_shipping_address(); ?></p>
```

And this before for a title:

```
 <h3><?php _e( 'Shipping address', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>
```

This can also be used:
 `<?php echo $order->get_shipping_address(); ?>`